# ubuntu 20.04 comes with python 3.8 .Is it possible to change default python version to 3.6.15 for a project?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

ubuntu 20.04 comes with python 3.8 .for a project to run i need default python version 3.6.15.Didnt find proper solution over the internet to change version to 3.6.15.please suggest.when tried to remove 3.8 ubuntu ran into problems.

gone through all possible pages giving solutions

Comment: You don't need to change/replace the existing one. You can have 2 versions of python installed, and leave the default system one alone. Then just make sure to use the correct `python3` and `pip` when installing packages and running your app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/2745495)

Comment: Hi @GinoMempin thanks for the quick reply. is it possible to remove python completely from ubuntu ?

Comment: No, **you don't want to do that**. You shouldn't be removing system built-ins, like the system pre-installed Python, because the system itself is using it. Like I said, just install a separate one for your project. I have 4 versions right now aside from the default python3.